# Htaccess в подкаталоге и передача параметров

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Есть два файла htacces. один в родительской директории с таким содержанием

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) sites/domaindir.com/$1 [L]
```

перенаправляет все запросы в подкаталог

файл лежащий в domaindir.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin /sites/domaindir.com/index.php       [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /sites/domaindir.com/index.php       [L,QSA]
```

перенаправляет запросы на index.php в корне сабкаталога.

При обращении пот урлу http;//domain.com/  все работает как надо, но при обращении по урлу
http://domain.com/about - странпица не найдена. Опытным путем было выявлено что дочерний htaccess всегда направляет на адресс без строки запроса.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в данном случае передать параметры?

Comment: @vitalyas, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Где QSA в последней строчке первого файла??